# SQL Selecting Matching Data from Another Table where matching columns have the same data

Tags: sql, ms-access

So I'm making a database of orders and I want to create a list of options for a dropdown box for an order form, but the list needs to be derived from a list of Services in another table, but it needs to match a preceeding Catagory Dropdown.

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. The query is below.

```
SELECT ServiceTypes.ServiceType 
FROM ServiceTypes 
WHERE Orders.ServiceCatagory = ServiceTypes.ServiceType;
```

So orders is the db of Orders I want to pull the list into
ServiceTypes has the lists of of ServiceTypes I want to pull. It's composed of ServicType and ServiceCatagory. I need to limit the list of Service Types based on the Service Types in Orders.

So if someone selects the ServiceCatagory in orders to be "InstalL", the only results from ServiceTypes I want are those that have a ServiceCatagory that equals the Orders Service Catagory.

I suspect I need to join but I'm not sure how or what kind.

**-update-**

I should point out, I'm doing this in Access and just trying to populate a listbox.

My new query looks like this

```
SELECT ServiceTypes.ServiceType
FROM ServiceTypes
INNER JOIN Orders ON Orders.ServiceCatagory = ServiceTypes.ServiceCatagory;
```

Still not sure if that's right

Comment: You are missing a `JOIN` with the `Orders` table.

Comment: So my mistake is using Where, when I should have something like,
INNER JOIN Orders On Orders.ServiceCatagory = ServiceType.ServiceCatagory

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Is the category part of the service table? If so, just do select from service where category = selected value and use that to populate your dropdown perhaps. If there results for the dropdown were returned in the form of a json payload, you could perhaps filter it client side too.. But I guess it would depend on size of all the service types you have to deal with.

Comment: There's a sepearte list of catagory's in a servicecatagorys table, which is fed into servicetypes. So anyone adding a servicetype has to use the correct servicecatagorys and can't just make their own thing up.

Answer (score 0):

So I've tested some of the SQL i've been using to get the information and I think I've actually got the correct code

```
SELECT ServiceTypes.ServiceType
FROM ServiceTypes
WHERE ServiceTypes.ServiceCatagory = Orders.ServiceCatagory
```

The real problem was my implementation in Access and where the query was being called.

I didn't need to use a JOIN, I just need to change where the call is being made. I.e. after the Catagory has been selected and not at the Database design level.